# What is the difference between hub.docker.com and dockerheart.com

Tags: docker, dockerhub

They seem almost identical. I can see the certificates are different and the sign-up page on dockerheart comes up with a warning like this:

[image]

Obviously I didn't try to login, so I don't know what happens if I do. Anyone knows if this is legit page or what it's all about?

Comment: seems like it's just an alias, more commonly `hub` is used.

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are two different, but one thing for sure if click login its redirect to ***Offical docker hub login*** website.
The signup button is updated for this screen https://www.dockerheart.com/pricing, which also points to the official docker hub website but for this https://www.dockerheart.com/signup screen seems like the page is not updated.

But for sign up, there is error and reCAPTCHA and the key is not valid. Below is the reason for the error

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq
[image]

Another thing Both resolve different IPs so hosted on different servers. Docker hub is hosted on AWS and dockerheart is on Cloudflare.

[image]

SSL is also issued by a different provider.

For official  docker hub

[image]

For dockerheart

[image]

API Calls for searching images

[image]

[image]

Seems like its docker registry.

One more interesting thing, I am not able to pull image from dockerheart.

```
docker pull registry.hub.docker.com/library/alpine
```

The above is working,

But this is not working..

```
docker pull dockerheart.com/library/alpine
```

Nor this one

```
docker pull registry.dockerheart.com/alpine
```